# Run background task every X amount of time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to start a service that once in awhile on all platforms has checked is there a notification to appear or not. Is there any nuget to connect all platforms or some examples?

Comment: You need to be more specific: why are you wanting to do this? What alternatives have you considered? For instance, Push Notifications. It is difficult to help without all the details

Comment: I want to run once a day a services to check if there is some notification to push, if there is simple show

Comment: Use Cron Job for it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan minutes)` method to start a background task that will repeat after the given time span. Here is a code example:

```
var minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes (3); 

Device.StartTimer (minutes, () => {

    // call your method to check for notifications here

    // Returning true means you want to repeat this timer
    return true;
});
```

This is included with Xamarin Forms, so you don't need any platform specific logic.

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(System.TimeSpan%2CSystem.Func%7BSystem.Boolean%7D)

Comment: It's not that, it is only the timer runs during application, I mean to run the service in the background

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best that you can do is following:

> Unfortunately, the way that these two platforms have evolved to handle executing background code is completely different. As such, there is no way that we can abstract the backgrounding feature into the Xamarin.Forms library. Instead, we going to continue to rely on the native APIs to execute our shared background task.

Further information for this topic can be found here:
  https://robgibbens.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/